# CasperJs catch error

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, casperjs

I don't understand how catch an error on CasperJs

I have this code

```
casper.thenClick('#activeCartViewForm > a');
```

And it return me sometimes :

```
[error] [remote] mouseEvent(): Couldn't find any element matching '#activeCartViewForm > a' selector
```

I would like to catch it and `this.die(errorMsg)` to stop my casperjs.

I try to add `waitForSelector` :

```
casper.waitForSelector('#activeCartViewForm > a', function() {
    this.click('#activeCartViewForm > a');
});
```

But already the same problem.

And when I did :

```
casper.on('step.error', function(err) {
    this.die("Step has failed: " + err);
});
```

Nothing happens

and when I did :

```
casper.on('resource.error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    this.die("Step has failed: " + err.errorString);
});
```

It fund me an error never saw before and stop my phantomjs :

```
[error] [phantom] Error: the remote server closed the connection prematurely 

[error] [phantom] Error: The request has been aborted 

[error] [phantom] Error: The request has been aborted 

[error] [phantom] Error: the remote server closed the connection prematurely
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch an error in CasperJS with the statement:

```
casper.on('error', function(msg, trace) {
    // process an error
});
```

You can try this working example:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.on('error', function(msg) {
    this.capture('error.png');
    this.die(msg);
});

casper.start('http://casperjs.org/', function() {
});

casper.thenClick('#activeCartViewForm > a');

casper.run();
```